# First Steps to becoming Jewish

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

Growing up, my mom was Christian and my dad was Jewish. We celebrated both Christian and Jewish holidays. Religion was a very confusing and uncomfortable topic for me. I am now 36, a mother, and married to a Catholic. I love my husband and am comfortable about his choice to be Catholic (he joined the church 2 months before our wedding). He knows that I do not accept Jesus Christ as the true Messiah, an he is comfortable with that. I have always believed more in the Jewish faith than Christian faith. Over the last few years I have longed for a deeper connection with God and feel "lost" not belonging. I'm wondering what steps I need to take to become an official Jew?

Comment: it's a long and demanding process. perhaps you should consider being connected to the jewish faith as a Noachide. (only seven basic commandments to observe)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Jennifer.  Your question has been asked before -- check out the duplicate link for lots of information!  Best wishes in your journey, and please do bring your other Judaism-related questions here as they come up.

Comment: @JenniferLuttes Definitely see the other question for more information. But one thing I would say in your particular case is that if you seek an Orthodox conversion, your husband will probably be required to convert with you (or else you have to divorce...or not convert). Whether to get a non-Orthodox conversion is up to you, although I would caution that a lot of non-Orthodox converts go through a lot of pain (which is the fault of the dissenting movements IMO) about not being considered a "real" Jew by all.

Comment: In your case, it might be best not to convert but to follow the [Noahide laws](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64305/5). It sounds like conversion in your case could destabilize an otherwise happy home.